# How do i store the value of sum in the new array b

Tags: java

```
public class HW9P1
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      /*int[][] a1 = { { 4, -2, 10 }, 
                     { 19, 3, -5 } };
      int[] b1 = coloumnsum(a1);*/

      int[][] a2 = { { 7, -10 }, 
                     { 4, 13 }, 
                     { 1, 0 } };
      int[] b2 = coloumnsum(a2);

      int i,j;
      for (i=0; i<b2.length; i++)
      {

         System.out.print(b2[i] + " ");


      }

  }
   public static int[] coloumnsum (int[][] a)
   {
      int[] b = new int[a[0].length];
      int i,j, sum= 7;

         for (j=0; j<a[0].length; j++)
         {
            for (i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            {
               sum = sum + a[i][j];


            }
         }
         return b;

   }
}
```

I have this code so far, which gives me the sum from the columns.Takes and 2d array and return 1d array. when i run this code, i get two 00 
For ex {2,4}
       {1,9} sum should be {3,13}

Comment: For the code i provided, the answer should be {12, 3}. I think i should also have to store the value of sum in the new array b, but i have no idea how to do it. For sum i hard coded the first value of a[0][0] to check if the code runs . and then for rows i used i and for columns i used j (first)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't storing your `sum` back into the array `b`. You actually don't need `sum`, just add the values directly in the array. Like,

```
public static int[] coloumnsum(int[][] a) {
    int[] b = new int[a[0].length];
    for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            b[j] += a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

When I make that change your current code produces (as expected)

```
12 3
```

Comment: i was comfortable with sum. I wanted to know how i do store the sum into the array.

Comment: @Asrar `b[j] = sum;` - of course, you'll need to set `sum = 0` before you start adding it (in every column).

Comment: One last thing                                                                                                   How do i print both b1 and b2 using one single loop. I                                                                                                         int[][] a1 = { { 4, -2, 10 }, 
                     { 19, 3, -5 } };
      int[] b1 = coloumnsum(a1);
      
      int[][] a2 = { { 7, -10 }, { 4, 13 }, { 1, 0 } } int[] b2 = coloumnsum(a2);

      int i,j;
      for (i=0; i<b1.length; i++)
      {
       System.out.print(b1[i] + " ");
         
        }

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know why you're starting the sum at `7` if all you want is
   to sum the columns of the 2D array.
2. you're not assigning anything to accumulator array `b`.

below illustrates the correct approach to sum the columns:

```
public static int[] coloumnsum (int[][] a)
{
       int[] b = new int[a[0].length];
       for (int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
               b[i] += a[j][i];                   
       }        
       return b;  
}
```

Comment: *you'd get an exception. However, with the changes made that should no longer be the case.* Try it with `int[][] a2 = {{1},{2,3},{3,4,5}};` - the problem is going to be `int[] b = new int[a[0].length];`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch my bad copy/paste issue. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That's the number of rows. There isn't a clean way to get the number of columns in a jagged array.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it's either this or risk having an exception... unless OP can guarantee that the 2D array will be a _true_ multidimensional array this is the safer approach.